OperatingSystemMXBean is giving strange values for getProcessCpuLoad and getCommittedVirtualMemorySize on Linux
I am trying to fetch some metrics about the machine and the Java process:
(Simplified code)
final OperatingSystemMXBean os = (OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();

while(true) {
    System.out.println("> RAM: " + os.getCommittedVirtualMemorySize());
    System.out.println("> CPU: " + os.getProcessCpuLoad());
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}

GraalVM 21 - Java 11 on Windows gives somewhat correct numbers (for once).
GraalVM 21 - Java 11 on Debian gives totally off numbers. The machine has 2 vCPU and 4GB RAM (no swap), and the output is:
> RAM: 39077724160
> CPU: 1.0
> RAM: 4717985792
> CPU: 0.0
> RAM: 4717985792
> CPU: 1.0

So from what I understand, my process varies between 0% and 100% CPU whereas it is basically sleeping all the time, and has a varying number of committed memory between 4.5GB and 37GB (more than total available memory).
Using top, pmap, /proc/meminfo, smem and others, all are indicating that the process is idle and uses about 175MB memory...
# smem -r -k
  PID User     Command             Swap      USS      PSS      RSS
47246 root     /jre/bin/java -        0   174.9M   175.3M   177.6M

# top
%Cpu(s):  0.1 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.8 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 47246 root      20   0 4607408 179928  42796 S   0.3   4.6   0:49.22 java

Should I consider that these numbers are plain wrong and this is a bug in the JRE (am I the only one experiencing this?), or is my interpretation of these numbers incorrect ?
For Reference:

double OperatingSystemMXBean.getProcessCpuLoad()
Returns the "recent cpu usage" for the Java Virtual Machine process.This value is a double in the [0.0,1.0] interval. A value of 0.0 meansthat none of the CPUs were running threads from the JVM process duringthe recent period of time observed, while a value of 1.0 means that allCPUs were actively running threads from the JVM 100% of the timeduring the recent period being observed. Threads from the JVM includethe application threads as well as the JVM internal threads. All valuesbetweens 0.0 and 1.0 are possible depending of the activities going onin the JVM process and the whole system. If the Java Virtual Machinerecent CPU usage is not available, the method returns a negative value.


long OperatingSystemMXBean.getCommittedVirtualMemorySize()
Returns the amount of virtual memory that is guaranteed tobe available to the running process in bytes,or -1 if this operation is not supported.


Are both virtual machines?

@aled no, the Linux machine is a VM and the Windows is my laptop. You think this may have an influence ?

I was wondering about that.
